# C++ linker error

Tags: c++

I have a file `A.cpp` which has the following lines:

```
#include"B.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ...
  char *input_file = *argv;  
  B *definition = new B(input_file);
  ...
}
```

In `B.h`, I have the following:

```
class B
{
  public:
   // Constructors
   B(void);
   B(const char *filename);
   ...
}
```

When I compile, I get the following error: `undefined reference to 'B::B(char const*)'`

Any suggestions on how to fix?

Thanks.

Comment: -1 Have you defined the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a definition for `B::B(char const *)`. You have provided only a declaration for `B::B(char const *)`, and the Linker is complaining that it can't actually find that function.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you specified the header for the function, but never actually wrote the body of the function.

You need to define the function I.E.

```
B::B(const char *filename){
  // Do stuff
}
```

in B.cpp.

Your problem doesn't have anything to do with const correctness.